# (Serverless offline schedule error) TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object

Tags: javascript, node.js, yaml, serverless, aws-serverless

I am trying to make a schedule cron job with npm serverless-offline-scheduler. but somehow I get an error about 'path' even if there is path option for schedule.
here is my serverless.local.yml file:

```
functions:
  assignTask:
    handler: src/taskHandler.run
    events:
      - schedule:
          enabled: true
          rate: rate(1 minute)

  students:
    name: ${self:custom.project}-${self:custom.environment}-students
    handler: src/handler.handler
    events:
      - http:
          method: any
          path: /students/
          cors: true
      - http:
          path: "/students/{proxy+}"
          method: any
          cors: true
```

I noticed from the bug that the yml file path is array of paths instead of just string. you see the console log I printed below
Here is err msg:

```
 Serverless: Offline [HTTP] listening on http://localhost:5002
[srv-file] Serverless: Enter "rp" to replay the last request
[srv-students] [ 'serverless.local.yml', 'serverless.local.yml' ] ----------
[srv-students]  
[srv-students]   Type Error ---------------------------------------------
[srv-students]  
[srv-students]   TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object
[srv-students]       at validateString (internal/validators.js:112:11)
[srv-students]       at Object.join (path.js:1039:7)
[srv-students]       at Utils.findServicePath (/Volumes/E/Students-NodeJS/services/students/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/Utils.js:111:31)
[srv-students]       at new Serverless (/Volumes/E/Students-NodeJS/services/students/node_modules/serverless/lib/Serverless.js:42:18)
[srv-students]       at /Volumes/E/Students-NodeJS/services/students/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless.js:76:24
[srv-students]       at tryCatcher (/Volumes/E/Students-NodeJS/services/students/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
[srv-students]       at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Volumes/E/Students-NodeJS/services/students/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)
[srv-students]       at Promise._settlePromise (/Volumes/E/Students-NodeJS/services/students/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
[srv-students]       at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Volumes/E/Students-NodeJS/services/students/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
[srv-students]       at Promise._settlePromises (/Volumes/E/Students-NodeJS/services/students/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:729:18)
[srv-students]       at Promise._fulfill (/Volumes/E/Students-NodeJS/services/students/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:673:18)
[srv-students]       at Promise._resolveCallback (/Volumes/E/Students-NodeJS/services/students/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:489:14)
[srv-students]       at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Volumes/E/Students-NodeJS/services/students/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:559:17)
[srv-students]       at Promise._settlePromise (/Volumes/E/Students-NodeJS/services/students/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
[srv-students]       at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Volumes/E/Students-NodeJS/services/students/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
[srv-students]       at Promise._settlePromises (/Volumes/E/Students-NodeJS/services/students/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:729:18)
[srv-students]       at Promise._fulfill (/Volumes/E/Students-NodeJS/services/students/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:673:18)
[srv-students]       at Promise._resolveCallback (/Volumes/E/Students-NodeJS/services/students/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:489:14)
[srv-students]       at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Volumes/E/Students-NodeJS/services/students/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:559:17)
[srv-students]       at Promise._settlePromise (/Volumes/E/Students-NodeJS/services/students/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
[srv-students]       at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Volumes/E/Students-NodeJS/services/students/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
[srv-students]       at Promise._settlePromises (/Volumes/E/Students-NodeJS/services/students/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:729:18)
[srv-students]       at Promise._fulfill (/Volumes/E/Students-NodeJS/services/students/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:673:18)
```

```
[srv-students]   Error --------------------------------------------------
[srv-students]  
[srv-students]   Error: Command failed: /Users/sr/.nvm/versions/node/v12.14.1/bin/node /Volumes/E/Students-NodeJS/services/students/node_modules/.bin/serverless invoke local --function assignTask --data {"account":"123456789012","region":"serverless-offline","detail":{},"detail-type":"Scheduled Event","source":"aws.events","time":"2020-05-06T00:10:35.467Z","id":"7377b012-268a-8bff-ee44-5b517f73704b","resources":["arn:aws:events:serverless-offline:123456789012:rule/assignTask"],"isOffline":true} --config serverless.local.yml --c serverless.local.yml
[srv-students]       at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:621:11)
[srv-students]       at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:639:15)
[srv-students]       at Scheduler._executeFunction (/Volumes/E/Students-NodeJS/services/students/node_modules/serverless-offline-scheduler/lib/scheduler.js:93:25)
[srv-students]       at Job.job (/Volumes/E/Students-NodeJS/services/students/node_modules/serverless-offline-scheduler/lib/scheduler.js:74:16)
[srv-students]       at Job.invoke (/Volumes/E/Students-NodeJS/services/students/node_modules/node-schedule/lib/schedule.js:173:10)
[srv-students]       at /Volumes/E/Students-NodeJS/services/students/node_modules/node-schedule/lib/schedule.js:552:11
[srv-students]       at Timeout._onTimeout (/Volumes/E/Students-NodeJS/services/students/node_modules/node-schedule/lib/schedule.js:510:7)
[srv-students]       at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
[srv-students]       at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7)
```

my package versions:

```
    "@types/node": "^12.12.28",
    "serverless": "^1.63.0",
    "serverless-dotenv-plugin": "^2.3.2",
    "serverless-offline": "^5.12.1",
    "serverless-offline-scheduler": "^0.4.2",
    "serverless-webpack": "^5.3.1",
```

Comment: Did you try not using quotes in this `path: "/students/{proxy+}"`?

Comment: @stamstam No. that path is not related to this issue, just look at the error message.
The path array [ 'serverless.local.yml', 'serverless.local.yml' ]  are printed out instead of just 'serverless.local.yml' to find out the handler function. I am not sure why it is array of string.

Comment: Yes, there is no validation step for **config** input from CWD